# Copy data from Excel to SQL database - Not uploading all Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, excel

I am uploading data from an Excel file to a SQL Server database using a ASP.NET 4.7 website. Actually this is a DotNetNuke website.

I am using the following code. This is the exact method I am using in my code.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

So this code is working and I can transfer my Excel data to the SQL Server database.

My problem is the transferring data limit.

It is not transferring all the data. When I have more records and more columns, then it is transferring only the first records only.

Usually, my Excel files are about 3 MB and It has 60 000 records or more. But it passes only about 18000-25000 records. When I remove some Excel columns and pass only a few columns, it increases the number of records. When I upload only one column, then it is passing all the records. When I add columns one by one, then the number of copied records are decreasing.

I feel, there is a limitation of the data that we can pass. How can I increase this?

In the `web.config`, I changed the settings like this:

```
<!-- allow large file uploads -->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" shutdownTimeout="21600" 
             executionTimeout="60000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" 
             maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2097151" 
             maxUrlLength="2048" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" 
             enableVersionHeader="false" requestValidationMode="2.0" 
             fcnMode="Single" />
```

But no luck. That did not change anything.

What else should I consider for this?

- Server settings? (I have RDP access)
- App Pool Settings?
- Website Settings?
- SQL Server settings?
- Database settings?
- Is there a limitation with the code that I am using?

Please, can you advise on this? I really appreciate your support on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Excel 2003 had a limit of 64,000 rows per worksheet (xls).   You can have more rows in 2007+ (xlsx).  So if you are using JET drive for oledb (or specifying xls filename) you will be limitied to 64,000 rows.  Recently I found that in latest excel with xlsx files you could only import 1,000,000 rows per worksheet.

Comment: I can pass only 18151 or something like that. If I delete some columns, then I can pass more.

I am using 


<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>

    <add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'"/>

I am using the exact code as per the reference link in my question.

Comment: You may just have bad data at row 18151.  Try IMEX option.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/.  Does column 1 have data in every row?

Comment: No. That is not the reason. I used different files with different data. 18151 is the example count I said. If I remove column by column then the records count is increasing accordingly.

Comment: Please, anybody is there to help me? I really appreciate your support me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but I've been working with excel for a long time and have not seen limits based on the amount of data.  Usually these type of issues are related to the number of row/columns, or errors.  I've seen corrupted workbooks and seen bad data in cells.  One suspicion is you deleted a lots of rows so the deleted row are being included in the 64000 row limit.  I would make a new workbooks.  Then copy the worksheet from old to new workbook.  Then try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried your suggested methods.
I created a new file and just copied the first 10 records and repeated it and made 90000 records. Still, it is coping ~19000 records.
I have tried with more than 40 different excel files now.
There is something on this. I was also searching and I do not see any limitation.
Are there any settings to change in the server settings or database settings or need to change anything on the code?
I can see you have a much better experience. Hope you will have a good idea about this issue.

Comment: It may be the memory size.  Repeat the test of copying rows and check filesize between each copy.  I usually refer to Microsoft Limits on these issues.  The following page is the latest limits for a xlsx file (not xls before office 2003) : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am also thinking this is something like a memory limit or something. 
My file size is a maximum of 5MB. But the record count is about 90000.
How can I see the memory limit and where can I increase this? AppPool or Database SQL server?
Thank you very much again for your support.

Comment: Use a file explorer,  You probably need to refresh after each save.  Are you using ACE or JET?  The only time I've seen issues like this is when cells in first column are empty.  Are there any Primary Keys defined in the SQL Table?

Comment: <add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'" />

Yes. I have an autoincrement primary key in the table.
All other columns are allowing NULL values. There are no empty values in my testing file. No empty values in the first column and any column.
I want to save all records in the excel file. Not partial records.

Please, can you advise me? Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Thank you very much @jdweng for supporting me. I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue.

I was using my connection string to the excel file like this.

```
<add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'" />
```

I added 'IMEX=1;' to it like below.

```
<add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'" />
```

This fixed my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: That was my suggestion.  Using IMAX treated the data as text rather than an object.  The JET/ACE treat data as Excel does with GENERAL Format and attempts to guess types.  Often guessing wrong.  IMAX disables the guessing and treats data as strings.

Comment: Yes. I appreciate much your great support. I did not have an idea of how to use the IMEX option and I didn't recognize there is such an option.
Your experience was too helpful to find this solution. Thank you.